# semaphore (gui ansible) can forward root password

Tags: ansible

I am having this yaml for ubuntu Cleaner

```
    ---
- name: Clean up system files
  hosts: pc
  remote_user: user
  become: yes
  vars:
    ansible_become_password: "{{ vault_password }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Clean apt cache using apt-get
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: apt-get clean

    - name: Remove unused packages and dependencies
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        autoremove: yes
        autoclean: yes

    - name: Remove old compressed log files
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: "/var/log"
        patterns: "*.gz"
        age: "1w"
        recurse: no
      register: log_files

    - name: Delete old compressed log files
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ log_files.files }}"
      when: log_files.files|length > 0

    - name: Remove thumbnail cache
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "~/.cache/thumbnails/*"
        state: absent

    - name: Remove old snap revisions
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        set -eu
        snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |
        while read snapname revision; do
          sudo snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
        done
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
```

i created ansible-vault password and enter password in file. But i get error from semaphore permission denied

[image]

Comment: You are not using `become` and are running `apt` without `root` privileges.

Comment: Yes, it looks like user permission issue. You can provide SUDO creds in Semaphore's Inventory.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `become: yes` globally. I wouldn't suggest that, but using it at each task. Of course, unless all the tasks needed sudo privileges.

Here:

```
tasks:
    - name: Clean apt cache using apt-get
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: apt-get clean
```

You may want to use the the [ansible.builtin.apt module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html). Also, you need to run this with privileges:

```
tasks:
  - name: Clean apt cache using apt-get
    ansible.builtin.apt:
      clean: True
    become: True
```

Also, in case you may be mixing some concepts:

The `ansible_become_password` and the `vault_password` are different things.

While the `ansible_become_password` is the password of the user you want to become (see [privilege escalatio](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html)n), the `vault_password` is the one you would use to decrypt the actual password of the user, which is stored in Ansible Vault.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide SUDO credentials in Inventory.

[image]

Comment: This user is a sudo also, so I provide it at first time, su in Type is File, and user crendetial and sudo crendetials are the same, cause that user is in sudoers.

Comment: You need `become: true`

Comment: Where do you mean it